# Text search in C#/EF with boolean queries (AND, OR, NOT) for a Postgres DB

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, search, entity-framework-core

I'm using a Postgres DB that I'm accessing trough C# and Entity framework. I have a web interface to perform queries towards the database. Today I have a text search where I match the text inputed by the user like this:

```
EF.Functions.ILike(x.Text, $"%{SearchString}%")
```

But this only matches the whole phrase inputed by the user. I would like the ability to add more advanced searches that include AND, OR and NOT.

```
User input: (car OR auto) AND (volvo OR bmw) AND NOT crashed
```

I would like the search to be case insensitive, that is why I use EF.Functions.ILike today

So I have two questions:

- When the user inputs the search query need to be parsed and broken down into into a structure that can be used in the EF query, any tips here?
- How can the EF query be written to get the desired functionality?

Thank you in advance for any tips

Comment: You're essentially building a domain-specific language for filtering records. You'll need a parser to process the expression into a suitable query.

Comment: If all you want is OR, AND and NOT, then it would be pretty easy to parse. Do you want to have [Bob OR Bill] or ["Bob" OR "Bill"]. The latter is more work to parse, but doable. You may want to make your keywords be something like $OR and $AND. Then take a look at _Predicate Builder_ for creating you EF queries

Comment: I would take a long hard think if this is really the best approach. Databases do not like free text searches. And users do not like writing complex expression. You should probably try to organize your data better, and provide the users with a UI to do filtering.